# How to implement a token field in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I need to implement a token field in Angular.js.

I have found this token field that uses Bootstrap: http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#usage.

Before writing a directive for it, I was wondering if such a directive already existed, or if there was better/easier options for Angular.js.

Thanks!

Comment: What's a token field?

Comment: A token field is a control that creates a token out of a user’s text input.  A good example is when you add "Tags" to a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it calls `ngTagsInput`.

Find more here:

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngTagsInput

Demo link:

http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

Comment: Looks promising.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks!